# ExtJs 4, is there a way to find control? (not by "id")

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have button with `id = 'someid'`, i can find it by `Ext.getCmp('someid')`...

**Is there a way to set some kind of "extraId" to that button, and find that button by "extraId'?**

Comment: nope there isn't one. You access the button component from parent container using primitive javascript node property[which is not recommended when comes to extjs as it is Abstraction].

Comment: No, ExtJS doesn't provide any such mechanism. But you can create a manager Object for storing these buttons with some key/value (id/button object) and retrieve them according to that id.

Comment: I know :) but.. i want to do something like this.. is there a way to do so? This don't have to be exacly a build in ExtJs function...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question is where you want to search to get your item.

Another way could be the *itemId*.

> An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a component when no object reference is available.  Instead of using an id with Ext.getCmp, use itemId with Ext.container.Container.getComponent which will retrieve itemId's or id's. Since itemId's are an index to the container's internal MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to the container -- avoiding potential conflicts with Ext.ComponentManager which requires a unique id.

Source and further documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId

The *ComponentQuery* (mentioned by wombleton) is also a good way but maybe not as performant as the *itemId*.

Comment: Yes, I suggest using itemId=OK as well. Also consider using up() or down(). So you probably have an event from some component. You can go component.down('button#ok')

Answer (score 8):

You can search for it by doing an [`Ext.ComponentQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

Example that will work in the console on the linked page:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[text=OK]')
```

You can replace `text=OK` with the attribute you are searching for.

Comment: Very useful.  For a long time, I've been struggling for a way to reference the Dekstop object or the taskbar object from the Ext example.  Realizing that the desktop's the only thing with a taskbar, this works perfectly: Ext.ComponentQuery.query("[taskbar]")[0]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the ExtJS 4 API docs, but I know that in 3.X and previous verions have some other ways of getting references to your compoents without the use of the DOM ID.

If your components are part of a form or form panel, you should have access to a method called findField(). It is inherited from Basic Form.  This method can take an id, dataIndex, name, or hiddenName to get a reference to your component.

There is also a helper method called findByType(xtype) that you can use to try and find your buttons.  Another option would be to extend the button you use to place a unique property that you can use as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to id is itemId and it is limited to the scope of the container in which it is defined. So, in this case, there is not need to define globally unique itemId as done in case of id. We can use component query to get the component object having the itemId. Please follow  this link where i have posted about how to use itemId and what is its benefit.
 http://jksnu.blogspot.in/2012/11/use-itemid-instead-of-id.html